# Django dropdown loop

Tags: html, django

My html code

```
{% for nav in firstloop %}
<li class="has-dropdown">
<a href="/{{ nav.slug }}">{{ nav.title }}</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
{% for dropdown in secondloop %}
{% if nav.title == dropdown.parent.title %}
<li><a href="/{{ dropdown.slug }}">{{ dropdown.title }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

My context

```
def homepage(request):
    try:
        return {
            "homepage": Page.objects.get(parent__isnull=True),
        }
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return {'homepage':''}


def firstloop(request):
    try:
        return {
            "firstloop": Page.objects.filter(parent=Page.objects.filter(slug="home"),),
        }
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return {'firstloop':''}

def secondloop(request):
    try:
        return {
            "secondloop": Page.objects.exclude(parent=Page.objects.filter(slug="home"),),
        }
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return {'secondloop':''}
```

The problem is a page with no "dropdowns" still renders the class "has-dropdown" in the div.  so how do I create a statement that if the page has no other pages attached to it doesn't display? Thanks, James!

Comment: just give a check in top of your template code like: {% if firstloop != '' %}

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the `secondloop` is not empty:

```
{% for nav in firstloop %}
{% if secondloop %}
...
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this is faster than using `count` in this case, because if the second loop contains items, it will be looped over anyway, and this method will execute the query and cache the results. `count` would result in two separate queries.

Comment: This didn't work, maybe try posting the full answer rather than part of the html code?

Comment: Because the secondloop is always going to exist if there is pages